# ArcMap Grid to Ground Click on map for the grid lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cogo, plss

I am using PLSS data found from this California [BLM data source](https://data.doi.gov/dataset/blm-ca-cadastral-plss-standardized-data-cadastralreference-version-1-0-cadnsdi) to map COGO'ed polygons. I am unsure if I should use the ground to grid correction function. When I do I use the click on the map for the ground to grid correction lines. After clicking for the start and ending for the ground to grid lines I do not receive any direction offset or distancing factors. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: More information please. A screen shot of the problem would be helpful.